# Is logging using SocketHandler asynchronous?

Tags: python, sockets, logging

I am running a basic logger using a `SocketHandler`; essentially a minor variant of this code: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/network-logging.html.

My question is, is the logging from the client asynchronous? *If* it is not, is there a way to enforce a timeout? i.e. essentially the client should wait for the logging to happen till 't' seconds and then move on. I have multiple processes logging through the same server.

Comment: I want to say yes. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.4/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L285 this is the main definition, it implements `Handler` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.4/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L551 which sure has a lot of `lock()`s

Answer (score 0):

It's asynchronous in the sense that it can handle inputs from multiple processes interleaved with each other, but not asynchronous in the sense that the calls to sockets are blocking. Since each client connection is handled in a new thread, this doesn't matter too much as long as there aren't *too* many client connections.